# Using serial API's in Tkinter with Python 3.4 on Linux

Tags: tkinter

I am trying to write a serial port terminal GUI in Tkinter using Python 3.4. 
I am using Linux Platform and PyCharm IDE. I understand that for reading through the serial port I need some sort of serial package based on Python 3.4. I have googled and found one on: https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pyserial.

But for Linux I do not find any serial package for Python 3.4. Its for Python 2.7. Has anybody used serial API's in Tkinter with Python 3.4?

Also does it makes sense to install pyserial-2.7.tar.gz provided in link to Python 3.4 locally?  I am not sure how to do that using pip for Python 3.4.

Also I tried running sudo apt-get install python-serial as I am using Ubuntu, but this also doesn't work when I try to use any serial API's.

Can anybody provide some information on this stuff. Thanks.

Comment: readthedocs.org says "Python 2.7 or newer, including Python 3.4 and newer".  There are also instructions in the docs on how to install with pip. I have no idea what "but this also doesn't work when I try to use any serial API's" means.

Comment: So you mean that you installed pyserial-2.7.tar.gz in Python 3.4 though pip but still you weren't able to call any serial API in Python 3.4. Is it?